# How can I separate working hours with javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

This is my example.

```
9.00 - 18.00
```

I want to separate working hours like this

```
9.00 - 10.00
10.00 - 11.00
11.00 - 12.00
12.00 - 13.00
13.00 - 14.00
14.00 - 15.00
15.00 - 16.00
16.00 - 17.00
17.00 - 18.00
```

This is my code,it is working well

```
let facility[0]['working_hours'] = 9.00 - 18.00
//SEPARATED WORKING HOURS
            let dateArray  = facility[0]['working_hours'].match(/\d+/g);

            let time_1 = parseInt(dateArray[0]);
            let time_2 = parseInt(dateArray[2]);

            let start_date_time = [],end_date_time = [];

            let j = 0;
            for(let i = time_1; i < time_2 + 12; i++){
                start_date_time[j] = `${i > 12 ? i - 12 : i}.00`;
                end_date_time[j] = `${i + 1 > 12 ? i + 1 - 12 : i + 1}.00`;

                j++;
            }
```

But I want to change my code,making it more stable using moment.js or another good example which you suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Initial input
const hours = '9.00 - 18.00';

// '9.00 - 18.00' -> [ 9, 18 ] -> const start = 9, const end = 18
const [start, end] = hours.split(' - ').map(parseFloat);

// Push each hour block to allHours.
const allHours = [];
for (let curStart = start; curStart < end; curStart++) {
  // Note: need toFixed(2) here to convert from number 9 to string '9.00'
  allHours.push(`${ curStart.toFixed(2) } - ${ (curStart + 1).toFixed(2) }`);
}

console.log(allHours);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it right, you just need to update the last part of your code to:

```js
let working_hours = [[], []];
for(let i = time_1; i < time_2; i++){
    working_hours[0].push(`${i}.00`);
    working_hours[1].push(`${i + 1}.00`);
}
```

## Edit:

Now using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

```
let working_hours = '9.00 - 18.00';
let dateArray  = working_hours.split(' - ');

let start = moment(dateArray[0], 'H.m');
let end   = moment(dateArray[1], 'H.m');

let start_date_time = [],end_date_time = [];

let max = start.hour() + end.diff(start, 'hours');
for(let hour = start.hour(); hour < max; hour++){
    start_date_time.push(`${hour}.00`);
    end_date_time.push(`${hour + 1}.00`);
}
```

Comment: I want to change all code,using moment js or another good example

Comment: I'll take a look into moment.js and update the answer.

Comment: Updated the answer. Pretty easy to understand code, any help you need might be solved by looking at the functions used in the moment.js docs.